# The relationship of deteminant of a matrix and its diagonol block matrix?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, inequalities, proof-theory

I am trying to prove an inequality that :
$$
\operatorname{det} \Sigma_{V \mathrm{~V}}<\prod i \operatorname{det}\left(\Sigma_{V_{i} V_{i}}\right)
$$
Where
$$
\Sigma_{V V}=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
\Sigma_{V_{1} V_{1}} & \cdots & \Sigma_{V_{1} V_{k}} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\Sigma_{V_{k} V_{1}} & \cdots & \Sigma_{V_{k} V_{k}}
\end{array}\right]$$
is a corvariance matrix, all of its block matrix is postive definite and Symmetric.

Any one may help me please? Thank you very much.